# Should I always retrieve full object from a database?

Tags: java, oop, database-design, architecture, orm

This is a very simple question that applies to programming web interfaces with java. Say, I am not using an ORM (even if I am using one), and let's say I've got this Car (id,name, color, type, blah, blah) entity in my app and I have a CAR table to represent this entity in the database. So, say I have this need to update only a subset of fields on a bunch of cars, I understand that the typical flow would be:

1. A DAO class (CarDAO) - getCarsForUpdate()
2. Iterate over all Car objects, update just the color to say green or something.
3. Another DAO call to updateCars(Cars cars).

Now, isn't this a little beating around the bush for what would be a simple select and update query? In the first step above, I would be retrieving the entire object data from the database: "**select id,name,color,type,blah,blah.. where ..from CAR**" instead of "**select id,color from CAR where ...**". So why should I retrieve those extra fields when post the DAO call I would never use anything other than "color"? The same applies to the last step 3. OR, say I query just for the id and color (select id,color) and create a car object with only id and color populated - that is perfectly ok, isn't it? The Car object is anemic anyway?

Doesn't all this (object oriented-ness) seem a little fake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one, I would prefer that if the RDBMS can handle your queries, let it. The reason is that you don't want your JVM do all the work especially when running an enterprise application (and you have many concurrent connections needing the same resource).

If you particularly want to update an object (e.g. set the car colour to green) in database, I would suggest a SQL like

```
UPDATE CAR SET COLOR = 'GREEN';
```

*(Notice I haven't used the **WHERE** clause)*. This updates **ALL** `CAR` table and I didn't need to pull all `Car` object, call `setColor("Green")` and do an update.

In hindsight, what I'm trying to say is that apply engineering knowledge. Your DAO should simply do fast select, update, etc. and let all SQL "work" be handled by RDBMS.

Comment: Updating the entire table wouldn't make sense, when I want to update only a bunch of cars based on some criteria (where condition), would it?

Comment: The question really is.. why do we like to act like we are reading from an RDBMS into an object when these two things are entirely different spaces? Tables are not objects, objects are not tables.

Comment: @Jay, still, can you write a SQL query that handles your condition? If you can, then let the RDBMS execute the Query rather than you pull it in Java and do update yourself.

Comment: The similarity is that there is relationship in both spaces. RDBMS uses keys whereas Objects uses inheritance, composition, etc. as relationship between objects. The hard job is to correlate them between these 2 spaces. That's where Software engineering comes in. It's not about coding but engineering. :-)

Comment: Ok. So you are saying, do something like "update CAR set COLOR=GREEN where ID in (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ?" Wouldn't that affect performance?

Comment: Not on the JVM side, since the RDBMS does the compilation and execution of the SQL Script (assuming you've indexed your tables, etc).

Comment: @Jay It would affect the performance in a very positive way. Everything is done server-side and you avoid expensive download and re-upload of data from/to the server. Plus, it'll potentially let the DBMS produce more optimal query plan (i.e. do it all in a single pass provided right indexes are present). Plus, it could (depending on DBMS) have subtle concurrency implications that you may want (e.g. Oracle will always provide consistent data view in a single statement - you'd have to use SERIALIZABLE transactions to achieve the same with two statements).

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman got it and Thank you Branko. Here's the question, so what is the point of having a Car class defined in my code anyway, IF all my code does is a bunch of updates that are best done on the database side? What is the point of ORMs?

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman one more question here, so what you are saying is "write a stored procedure, that FETCHES car_ids > timestamp, then UPDATES color to green on these car_ids" or may be just an sql if it is simpler than that. Would you not be worried that all your code will end up in the database if you rely too much on stored procs? I mean, one would endup storing business rules in these conditions inside stored procs, wouldn't one?

Comment: I don't suggest stored procs as it can be a pain porting it to other RDBMS. The reason for ORM is so that for us to work in Java space throughout. We have a `Car` object and we say `CarDAO.save(car)`. The implementation of `CarDAO`, however varies. It can be `FileCarDAO`, `MySQLCarDAO`, `ApacheCassandraCarDAO`, `BinaryCarDAO`, etc, i.e., We should create an abstraction between objects and persistence.

Comment: Right. How often does that happen? I mean, how often do applications go through a database type change? I understand where you are coming from. Anyway, let me make this simpler. I have a User table, I need to retrieve UserIds, query an external webservice which gives me 9/10 column details for this table. So, In the first case, where I retrieve userids, would it make sense to retrieve the entire object. I am sorry that this conversation is getting longer and longer. I am a little confused about the whole approach to where I should cast to object and where I shouldn't

Comment: Ask yourself, when pulling the `User`, are you going to use all the fields there? If not, why waste resources? Pull what you need and if you everything (e.g. doing user maintance of the table) then do so. In my case, I pull everything that I know won't change over time and it referenced in more than 1 pages (e.g. user registration/update). That way, I don't constantly poll the RDBMS. As I said before, it depends on your requirement. You need to engineer your system to fit your functional and non-functional requirement. That's being a software engineer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, what I can say is :
As long as you're not doing join operations, i.e. just querying columns from the same table, the number of columns you fetch will change almost nothing to performance. What really affects performance is how many rows you get, and the where clause. Fetching 2 or 20 columns changes so little you won't see any difference.
Same thing for updating

Comment: "almost nothing" - this really depends on the table and data you are fetching, doesn't it? What about network performance? What about fetching huge texts? It does affect performance in an app that fetches stuff from a remote database?

Comment: What you're trying to do is over optimisation. You would be complicating your life and app immensly by only fetching and updating specific fields. And it will gain you nothing. Of course, if you have very specific cases, like a column with huge text in it, you should design a specific solution. But that's a different question :)

Comment: I'll second jonasr on the fact that reducing the number of selected columns usually has a limited impact on performance. The DBMS will basically fetch the whole row in one go anyways. The only difference I see is in network transfer speed should you have very large columns. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194424/effect-of-number-of-projections-on-query-performance. 

If you really see an improvement in object loading in your context, you could implement lazy loading of large columns (BLOBs, CLOBs, etc.) but that would force you to rewrite something that ORMs already do out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in certain situations, it *is* useful to request a subset of the fields of an object.  This can be a performance win if you have a large number of columns or if there are some large `BLOB` columns that would impact performance if they were hydrated.  Although the database usually reads in an entire row of information whenever there is a match, it is typical to store `BLOB` and other large fields in different locations with non-trivial IO requirements.

It might also make sense if you are iterating across a large table and doing some sort of processing.  Although the savings might be insignificant on a single row, it might be measurable across a large table.

Also, if you are only using fields that are in indexes, I believe that the row itself will never be read and it will use the fields from the index itself.  Not sure in your example if `color` would be indexed however.

All this said, if you are only persisting objects that are relatively simple without `BLOB` or other large database fields then this could turn into premature optimization since the query processing, row IO, JDBC overhead, and object creation are most likely going take a lot more time compared to hydrating a subset of the fields in the row.  Converting database objects into the final Java class is typically a small portion of the load of each query.